# java nlp - extract number from string

Tags: java, nlp

I am having trouble extracting a number from a string usering nlp. ( similiar to PrettyTime for nlp date parsing)

Is there any java library out there to achieve this? For example:
I need to extract the number 2 from this string: "choose the second one" or "pick number two"

Thanks for your help and time!
Subby

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Duckling can extract several entities, numeral is one of them. Here is the link - https://github.com/facebook/duckling. Here is an example -

Dimension   Example input   Example value output
Numeral     "eighty eight"  {"value":88,"type":"value"}

Answer (score 0):

if the string is a digit, "2" for example then you can get the value with this

```
Integer.valueOf(String);
```

an example is

```
 String number = "24";
 int numberFromString;
 numberFromString = Integer.valueOf(number);
```

but if you're asking about turning numbers as words into an int, I have no idea, sorry.